# How to use VNImageRequestHandler for multiple image input?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am new CoreML and trying to make working a coreml model which is required 3 image input and one output. I created VNCoreMLRequest with model file and trying to run it by using VNImageRequestHandler but there is no init available for VNImageRequestHandler to pass more than one image.Is there any other alternative RequestHandler which I can use to pass multiple image input or is it possible with VNImageRequestHandler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the regular Core ML API, not Vision. This requires you to convert the images to CVPixelBuffer objects. My repo [CoreMLHelpers](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers) has code for this.

Comment: Hi @Matthijs Thanks for response,  can you provide some reference or demo on passing CVPixelBuffer input to regular  core ml APIs (I thing to model.predict function). I am not finding ways to do that. Thanks

Comment: Pretty much any beginner Core ML tutorial on the web will show you how to do that. I also sell a book that goes into great detail on this and pretty much every other aspect of Core ML (see my profile).